# whitespace at last line of file always recognized as EOF?

Tags: python, text, eof

I know this is probably a question asked before and I have searched for some answers, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

But I am still very confused and I want to ask it again for a definite answer.

My question is: **Is an empty line with only whitespace characters, such as the newline character (/n), when placed as the last line of a file, always treated as EOF by Python? What about other languages such as PHP, Javascript etc? Any OS platform differences?**

For example, in my python3 code, I have a file to process:

```
some text at line 10
some more text at line 11
nothing (last line of file)
```

My code recognizes the last line as EOF, and raises StopIteration exception. If I do not have the last empty line, the code works without the exception (I am using `open() as f: for line in f` so literally it does have EOF but captured internally). The text editor I used is VisualStudio and notepad, tried both.

For the same text file, if I concatenate it to itself, the new file does not have the newline in between them. That's the reason I think the last empty line is just treated as EOF and ignored.

Thank you.